# Unity 2d with Astar pathfinding

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am using Astar pathfinding in my 2d game but there is a problem.When an enemy follows the player and shoots after stopping at a particular distance from the player it doesn't see whether there is an object between between them and shoots directly at the obstacle.I want the enemy to move around the obstacle and shoot when there is no object between them.
I know we can use Raycast but I don't know how to implement it....

Answer (score 3):

```
public void CheckRayCast()
     {
         RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, target.position, 50f);
      
         if (hit)
         {
             Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
 
         }
     }
```

You can use this code to check whether a object is hit or not

Comment: Thanks a lot....But actually after checking for the object hit, how should I command the enemy game object to move around the obstacle and then shoot at player when there is no obstacle in between.

Comment: add tags to the walls as obstacles, if the hit is a obstacle don't shoot, if isn't shoot

Comment: This shows how to implement a raycast but doesn't answer OPs question. To be fair: The question is to broad and therefore off-topic => [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions) .. Neither the question nor this answer brings a real value to this community and future readers ;)